# R Code Programming: filling missing column values down first and then up on a stacked sorted table

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, but the 3rd column has some missing values which need to be filled in with the following logic.

The desired result is that there are no missing values on the 3rd column (part), to fill it we must find first "week" in which there is a "part" value filled in for that particular "item" (1st column) and then filling it in by copying the "part" down until a new value of "part" is found. Then repeat the copying process going down as until a new "item" row is found.

Finally, repeat the filling process for each "item" now going up since there might have been some blanks before the first "week" there was a "part" filled in.

Here is example data frame:

```
item=c(rep("A",7),rep("B",3),rep("D",5))
part=c("","","X","","Y","","","","Z","","","T","U","","")
week=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","1","2","3","10","11","12","13","14")
df=data.frame(item,week,part)
```

The desired resulting data frame looks like this:

```
item2=c(rep("A",7),rep("B",3),rep("D",5))
part2=c("X","X","X","X","Y","Y","Y","Z","Z","Z","T","T","U","U","U")
week2=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","1","2","3","10","11","12","13","14")
df2=data.frame(item2,week2,part2)
```

Help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a "last observation carried forward" task

```
library(zoo)
levels(df$part)[1] <- NA

df$part <- with(df,
  ave(part, item, FUN=function(x) {
    x <- na.locf(x,na.rm=FALSE)
    x[is.na(x)] <- na.omit(x)[1]
    x
  })
)

#   item week part
#1     A    1    X
#2     A    2    X
#3     A    3    X
#4     A    4    X
#5     A    5    Y
#6     A    6    Y
#7     A    7    Y
#8     B    1    Z
#9     B    2    Z
#10    B    3    Z
#11    D   10    T
#12    D   11    T
#13    D   12    U
#14    D   13    U
#15    D   14    U

all.equal(df,df2, check.names=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Please answer `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711655/r-populating-and-or-duplicating-rows-based-upon-other-columns` if possible