# R: populating and/or duplicating rows based upon other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, missing-data

My question is based upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614425/r-code-programming-filling-missing-column-values-down-first-and-then-up-on-a-st/35614728#35614728).

I have a data as below. I want to fill cells by first looking down and then by looking up as long as the bom is same. In case of bom=A, I want to fill up rows as shown. But in case of bom=B, as the type_p column is different, I want to duplicate rows and feel the blanks

```
bom=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",3))
Part=c("","lambda","beta","","tim","tom","")
type_p=c("","sub","sub","","sub","pan","")
ww=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3)
df=data.frame(bom,Part,type_p,ww)

> df
  bom   Part type_p ww
1   A                1
2   A lambda    sub  2
3   A   beta    sub  3
4   A                4
5   B    tim    sub  1
6   B    tom    pan  2
7   B                3
```

The final data that I want is as below

```
    bom Part    type_p  ww
1   A   lambda  sub      1
2   A   lambda  sub      2
3   A   beta    sub      3
4   A   beta    sub      4
5   B   tim     sub      1
6   B   tim     sub      2
7   B   tim     sub      3
5   B   tom     pan      1
6   B   tom     pan      2
7   B   tom     pan      3
```

## ________________________________________Update 1

The logic that I want is as below. Please remember that my data is very huge and I have thousands of values in each column.

bom and ww columns are always populated/filled in incoming data

1. Check if an entry in column bom has more than 1 value in the column type_p
2. If there is only 1 value then fill blanks in type_p and ww columns by first looking down and then looking up. In this case bom=A has only one value in type_p (sub)
3. If an entry in column bom has more than 1 unique value in type_p column then create additional sets of the same rows of that bom such that total sets will  be equal to distinct values in type_p column for that bom. In this case bom=B has two values in type_p (sub and pan)
4. Fill blanks in type_p and ww columns by first looking down and then looking up (look at the source row to fill up values)

**===========================================================Update 2**

After step 3, the data frame would look like below

```
> df
   bom   Part type_p ww
1    A lambda    sub  1
2    A lambda    sub  2
3    A   beta    sub  3
4    A   beta    sub  4
5    B    tim    sub  1
6    B                2
7    B                3
8    B                1
9    B    tom    pan  2
10   B                3
```

Comment: This is a very solvable problem, however your example does not follow your logic - you need to be a lot clearer around step 3 specifically, and how rows are filled up or down in the duplicated case. I would suggest showing intermediate data frames as well in your example (this might also help you work through the problem in your head)

Comment: Thats what I thought - so it seems like this violates your fill down principle. Should row 8 not be `tim sub`?

Comment: no. because as per my 2nd step, B value in column bom has 2 distinct values - sub and pan in column type_p, so we have to create an extra set of rows. In case of bom=A, we didnt create extra set of rows because we have only 1 value - sub in column type_p...Does it make sense now?

Comment: So you only apply the fill up/down within the groups of rows you create?

Comment: first (if required) we create rows and then only we fill up/down. We will take output of update 2 and then proceed to step 4 which fills empty cells

Comment: You placed the `tom pan` row in the second row of the created rows. Because of this, there is one row above that is blank. Based on your fill down principle within each distinct `bom` value, this should be filled with `tim sub`. In your desired output, it is `tom pan`, implying that you fill all blanks of a created row set with the Part and type_p of the source row

Comment: statement " In your desired output, it is tom pan, implying that you fill all blanks of a created row set with the Part and type_p of the source row " is correct. I might have worded it incorrectly in my original question. Is logic clear now? I also updated the original question

Answer (score 3):

With `tidyr` and `dplyr`, you could manage to do something near what you aim

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
# replacing empty string with NA
df <- df %>% mutate_each(funs(sub("^$", NA, .)), Part, type_p)
# filling missing values 
df <- df %>% fill(Part, type_p,.direction = "down") %>% fill(Part, type_p,.direction = "up")

df
#>   bom   Part type_p ww
#> 1   A lambda    sub  1
#> 2   A lambda    sub  2
#> 3   A   beta    sub  3
#> 4   A   beta    sub  4
#> 5   B    tim    sub  1
#> 6   B    tom    pan  2
#> 7   B    tom    pan  3
```

To obtain what you described (in question and comment), you could treat BOM A & B separately:

```
bind_rows(
  df %>% filter(bom == "A"), 
  df %>% filter(bom == "B") %>%
    complete(nesting(bom, Part, type_p), ww)
)
#> Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
#> 
#>       bom   Part type_p    ww
#>    (fctr)  (chr)  (chr) (dbl)
#> 1       A lambda    sub     1
#> 2       A lambda    sub     2
#> 3       A   beta    sub     3
#> 4       A   beta    sub     4
#> 5       B    tim    sub     1
#> 6       B    tim    sub     2
#> 7       B    tim    sub     3
#> 8       B    tom    pan     1
#> 9       B    tom    pan     2
#> 10      B    tom    pan     3
```

Comment: in case of BOM A, i dont want to to repeat rows as both parts beta and lambda are of type_c=sub. But in case of bom B, I want to have repeat rows because part - tim and tom are of different type_p - sub and pan. Also in case of ww, for B, i dont want ww=4 as it was not their in original data. FYI: bom A and bom B have no relationship at all/they are independent

Comment: is it possible to treat A and B separately ?
you could have the result you want doing, from my first `df`, 

`bind_rows(
  df %>% filter(bom == "A"), 
  df %>% filter(bom == "B") %>%
    complete(nesting(bom, Part, type_p), ww))`

Comment: I modified my answer. is it ok for you?

Comment: It looks correct. But the problem is i have thousands of different values in bom column. Is there easier way to loop through them?

Comment: Yes, you can apply a function for each value in BOM but, with your explanation, it seems that rules for BOM A et BOM B is different.
I would expect `[A, beta,  sub]` to have a `ww` value of `1,2,3,4`, not just `1,2` and the same for `[A, lambda,  sub]`, not just `3,4`.
is there a specific rule for each value of BOM ? If yes, it is not easy to find a general function for your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105032/discussion-between-titolondon-and-user2543622).